# Using Web Audio API analyser on Chromecast

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, chromecast, google-cast, web-audio-api

I'm trying to do some audio visualisation on the Chromecast receiver using [Web Audio API](https://plus.google.com/+LeonNicholls/posts/3Fq5jcbxipJ).

Unfortunately, the following code, that works well on Chrome, always returns an array of zeros for `getByteFrequencyData` on the Chromecast.

```js
$(function () {
    var context = new webkitAudioContext();

    var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = 64;
    analyser.minDecibels = -100;
    analyser.maxDecibels = -30;
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.9;
    var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

    var visualisation = $("#visualisation");
    var barSpacingPercent = 100 / analyser.frequencyBinCount;

    for (var i = 0; i < analyser.frequencyBinCount; i++) {
        $("<div/>").css("left", i * barSpacingPercent + "%")
            .appendTo(visualisation);
    }
    var bars = $("#visualisation > div");

    function update() {
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);
        bars.each(function (index, bar) {
            bar.style.height = frequencyData[index] + 'px';
        });
    };

    $('audio').bind('canplay', function() {
        var source = context.createMediaElementSource(this);
        source.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(context.destination);
        update();
    });
});
```

Am I missing something or is this particular feature of Web Audio not supported on Chromecast?

Comment: There is a bug filed for this: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=270